Solving a recurrence relation using roots of a quadratic equation
if the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 = px + q$ are $\alpha,\beta$. since they are roots,
$$\alpha^2=p \alpha+q$$
$$\alpha^n=p \alpha^{n-1}+q \alpha^{n-2}$$
similarly can be proven from $\beta$, when
$S_n = \alpha^{n} + \beta^{n} \\
S_n = p(\alpha^{n-1} + \beta^{n-1})+q(\alpha^{n-2} + \beta^{n-2}) \\
S_n = pS_{n-1} + qS_{n-2}$
we can make a set of equations as,
$S_{n} = pS_{n-1} + qS_{n-2} \\
S_{n-1} = pS_{n-2} + qS_{n-3} \\
S_{n-2} = pS_{n-3} + qS_{n-4} \\
S_{n-3} = pS_{n-4} + qS_{n-5} \\
... \\
S_{3} = pS_{2} + qS_{1} \\
S_{2} = pS_{1} + qS_{0}$
to find $S_n$ we can either substitute the S value in the next equation to previous equation as,
$S_{n} = pS_{n-1} + qS_{n-2} \\
S_{n} = p(pS_{n-2} + qS_{n-3}) + qS_{n-2} \\
S_{n} = p(p(pS_{n-3} + qS_{n-4}) + qS_{n-3}) + q(pS_{n-3} + qS_{n-4})$
this can be repeated till $n=2$, but the expression becomes complicated quickly, another way is by using elimination of the intermediate terms as,
$S_{n} = pS_{n-1} + qS_{n-2} \\
S_{n} = p(pS_{n-2} + qS_{n-3}) + qS_{n-2} \\
S_{n} = (p^2+q)S_{n-2} + pqS_{n-3} \\
S_{n} = (p^2+q)(pS_{n-3} + qS_{n-4}) + pqS_{n-3} \\
S_{n} = (p^3+2pq)S_{n-3} + (qp^2+q^2)S_{n-4}$
this can too be repeated, but i did not see a pattern emerge, is there a way to get a closed formula with only $p$ and $q$ for $S_{n}$?

You can also write $a^n+b^n$ in terms of elementary symmetric functions, $s_1=a+b=p, s_2=ab=-q.$ It your write it out, you get: $$a^n+b^n=\sum_{i+2j=n}\frac{n}{i+j}\binom {i+j}ip^iq^j.$$

$$
S_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n = \left(\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2+4q}}{2}\right)^n + \left(\frac{p-\sqrt{p^2+4q}}{2}\right)^n
$$

You definitely can do it, and those are the right monomials $p^iq^j,$ but I'm not sure 100% about the coefficients. It was something like that, but I  am working from memory.

@thomas yes, using the quadratic equation to get the roots directly without simplifying anything was in the back of my mind, but didnt try it because i kind of wanted a sum formula, thanks either way

The way I worked out the formula was to use the generating function for $S_n.$ Specifically, $$F(z)=\sum_n S_n z^n=\frac1{1-\alpha z}+\frac1{1-\beta z}=\frac{2-pz}{1-(pz+qz^2)}.$$
Then $$F(z)=(2-pz)\sum_m (pz+qz^2)^m$$
The coefficient of $z^n$ in $(pz+qz^2)^m$ is the coefficient of $z^{n-m}$ in $(p+qz)^{m}$ which is $\binom{m}{n-m}p^{2m-n}q^{n-m}.$ Letting $i=2m-n, j=n-m,$ $i+j=m, i+2j=n$ and we get:
$$F(z)=(2-pz)\sum_{n}z^n\sum_{i+2j=n}\binom{i+j}{i}p^iq^j$$
So the coefficient of $z^n$ in $F(z)$ is:
$$2\sum_{i+2j=n}2\binom{i+j}ip^iq^j-\sum_{i'+2j'=n-1}\binom{i'+j'}{i'}p^{i'+1}q^{j'}$$
So the coefficient of $p^iq^j$ is: $$\begin{cases}2&i=0\\
2\binom{i+j}i-\binom{i+j-1}{i-1}&i>0
\end{cases}$$
For $i>0,$ this is equivalent to: $$\binom{i+j}i+\binom{i+j-1}{i}=\binom{i+j}i\cdot\left(1+\frac{j}{i+j}\right)=\frac n{i+j}\binom{i+j}{j}.$$ And this values also works when $i=0,n=2j$ if $n>0.$
So we get, for $n>0,$:
$$S_n=\sum_{i+2j=n}\frac n{i+j}\binom{i+j}ip^iq^j.$$

yes this is exactly what i wanted, thank you so much
